# CSS auto-width Layout without margin:auto

Tags: css

Is this possible with css (I can probably manage it with javascript):

Its basically a `margin: auto` effect, but i want a different background for each margin, so i'm looking for divs with auto-widths on either side of the (fixed-width) center div if that makes sense. Probs better visualized:

[image: Sample layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/guc9V/1/

Bit of a hack but it works.

I didn't use your width value as jsFiddle would need resizing to see how it works.

This essentially tells the divs to act as table-cells, so they will fill the containing div, which acts as the table. If you didn't specify the width of the middle div, each column would be 33% wide.

Comment: No description, no +1; but `table-cell` is the way to go…

Comment: +1 Good answer, i'm still fiddling, trying to get it to work in my app which is proving problematic.. (thanks to ext js, or my lack of skill with it)

Comment: There's a better (cross browser) solution. The OP would do good to read up on the very basics of CSS.