# scaling divs width with fixed div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with 100% width
In that div there are divs next to eachother. left, center, right.
The center has a width of 900px.
Left and right are 100%. I want to make the left and right scalable but it doesnt work.
Left and right goes full width...

```
<div> 100%
    <div>left 100%</div>
    <div>center 900px</div>
    <div>right 100%</div>
</div>
```

does someone know how to make it work?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860814/css-auto-width-layout-without-marginauto/11861156#11861156), [this](http://jsfiddle.net/guc9V/1/) was my jsFiddle.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work thanks to you. Mine is a little different by using 50% instead of 100% like yours. When I set it to 100% the left div takes all the width from the right div. Do you know why?

Comment: Try using "min-width" as well. Those will scale out automatically if there is more space. I've had luck with that.